# Quicksort Java code going to infinite loop

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

when i try to run the below quick sort code,its going to infinite loop.the last iteration is going to infinite loop.

```
class QuickSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5,2};
        QuickSort ob = new QuickSort();
        ob.sort(arr, 0,arr.length-1);
        for(int s:arr){
            System.out.print(" "+s);
        }
    }
    int partition(int[] arr,int l,int h){
        int piv = arr[h];
        int i=l-1;
        for(int j=l;j<=h-1;j++){
            if(arr[j] <= piv){
                i++;
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
        int tp = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1]=arr[h];
        arr[h]=tp;
        return i+1;
    }

    void sort(int[] arr,int l,int h){
        while(l<h){
            int p = partition(arr, l, h);
            sort(arr, l, p-1);
            sort(arr, p+1, h);
        }

    }
}
```

Kindly help,where it goes wrong.

Comment: Use a Debugger to find out what is happend

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: You forgot the base of recursive method ... exit condition

Comment: you can accept my answer if it helped you to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `while` loop, use `if` condition, as following.

```
if(l<h){
        int p = partition(arr, l, h);
        sort(arr, l, p-1);
        sort(arr, p+1, h);
    }
```

There is no need to call sort recursively in an infinite `while` loop. Loop is infinite because `l` and `r` will never be changed in the algo.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have used `while` in the sort method.  This results in infinite recursive calls which ultimately will cause `StackOverFlowException`.  As suggested in the comments, these are the common mistakes and you can easily find them by debugging (or simple dry run for simple algorithms).

You just need two recursive calls form each invocation of the method `sort` which satisfies the condition `(l < h )`
For this you need a `if` condition insteadof `while` loop as below.

```
void sort(int[] arr,int l,int h){
    if(l<h){
        int p = partition(arr, l, h);
        sort(arr, l, p-1);
        sort(arr, p+1, h);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`l` and `h` in `sort()` never change, so you'll always have `l < h == true`